# Removing list of list if any item in list of list is zero

Tags: python

I have a list of list where the sublist contains numbers that are either 0, 1 or 2.
I need to remove any sublist where any of the numbers are 0.

I tried this code:

```
l = [list(b) for b in x.Branches]
z = 0
list2 = filter(z, l)
print list2
```

But it keeps telling me that int is not iterable. the first line gets me my list from rhino grasshopper data, and my list is

```
[[1, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: The first argument to `filter` has to be a function. Try `list2 = filter(lambda x: 0 not in x, l)`.

Comment: That solved it, thank you! I have never used filter before, so this explanation helped greatly

Answer (score 1):

[filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) takes function as first argument, I actually got TypeError. That's because `0` is not a function and it is not callable.

```
In [49]: list(filter(0, l))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-fe89c490c585> in <module>
----> 1 list(filter(0, l))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

the way I tried is below, hope it helps

```
In [50]: is_zero = lambda x: x == 0

In [51]: is_all_zero = lambda x: all(map(is_zero, x))

In [52]: not_is_all_zero = lambda x: not is_all_zero(x)
```

- is_zero checks if x is zero
- is_all_zero checks if list is all zero
- not_is_all_zero get opposite output of is_all_zero

and now we can use not_is_all_zero to filter l

```
In [54]: list(filter(not_is_all_zero, l))
Out[54]:
[[1, 1, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
...
```

---

## Update

you want filter any of item is zero, so you can apply below function to filter the list

```
In [55]: is_any_zero = lambda x: any(map(is_zero, x))

In [56]: is_any_zero([0,1])
Out[56]: True

In [57]: is_any_zero([1,1])
Out[57]: False

In [59]: not_is_any_zero = lambda x: not is_any_zero(x)

In [60]: list(filter(not_is_any_zero, l))
Out[60]:
[[1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove lists containing at least one zero, you could use

```
res = [ls for ls in lst if 0 not in ls]
```

Here is a hacky way of removing all suslists consisting only of zeros, assuming all elements are non-negative:

```
res = filter(sum, lst)
```

This uses the fact that `bool(0) == False` and `bool(x) == True` for `x > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to accomplish the same task is this:

```
list_2 = list(filter(all, l))
```

Here, the `all` function evaluates to true if every element being evaluated is true. Since `bool(x)` is true for all non-zero values, `all(l)` is true if all values in `l` are non-zero.